# How to convert a set of strings into 'ONE' array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have some data in a form of string and I want them to be inside an array so I can filter them.

I've tried .split() but it created individual arrays NOT one array with all the data inside it.

This is how the part of data looks.

```
"Jane Doe"
"John Smith"
"Rose Benet"
list goes on
```

What is the best way to convert these strings into one array?

Here's what I've tried.

```
for (let i = 0; i < customerData.length; i++) {
    let arrays = customerData[i].name;
    function flatten(arr) {
        return [].concat(...arr);
        
    }
    console.log(flatten(arrays));
}
```

And the result was rather than adding all strings nicely into one array, it gave each string its own array like this.

```
Array(14)
0: "J"
1: "a"
2: "n"
3: "e"
4: " "
5: "D"
6: "o"
7: "e"
length: 8

Array(11)
0: "J"
1: "o"
2: "h"
3: "n"
4: " "
5: "S"
6: "m"
7: "i"
8: "t"
9: "h"
length: 10

list goes on
```

The desirable result would be:

```
['Jane Doe', 'John Smith', "Rose Benet" list goes on]
```

This is how 'CustomerData' is defined:

```
CustomerData = [
  {
   "index": 0,
   "name" : "A",
   "gender" : "male",
   "company" : "CC"
  },
  {
   "index": 1,
   "name" : "B",
   "gender" : "female",
   "company" : "DD"
}]
```

Here's what I have tried so far. In my React app, I want to make a search box so users can put in search term than filtered result will be displayed.

This is the React code.

```
state = {
  names: [],
  searchTerm: ''
}

editSearchTerm = (e) => {
   this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value });
 }

dynamicSearch = () => {
   for(let i = 0; i < customerData.length; i++) {
            
         this.setState({ names: customerData[i].name });

        }
    return this.state.names.filter(name => 
        name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    }
```

And when I try to type in some search term, React throws an error "TypeError: this.state.names.filter is not a function".

I assume the error msg means 'name' property should be an array. When I inspect in Chrome dev tool, 'customerData[i].name' returns as strings.

This is where I got stuck. I can't seem to get "name" values inside an array.

They either get into an array of their own, (so rather than Array(63), it shows Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)......in console.)

How can I convert 'customerData[i].name' into one array?

Comment: Use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Note that this is very basic JS syntax though, and any half-decent tutorial on JS will teach you how to do this. (just make sure to find one for modern JS. If the tutorial talks about document.write(), or alert(), find a different one)

Comment: Can you show us the attempted code snippet with `.split()`. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Wazeed, just edited my question with my attempt. Could you please have a look and advise for me. Thanks!

Comment: .split() does not create "individual arrays". It returns 1 array, splitting the string with whatever delimiter you specify. So either you don't understand arrays or you aren't describing your issue properly. Make a js fiddle with an example of your issue.

Comment: Can you show exactly how `customerData` is defined?

Comment: Hey Gershy, just updated my question showing how customerData is structured.

Comment: @MKK for future questions you should always include that kind of information - no one knew what you were talking about, since they couldn't see what `customerData` looked like! :) See my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have the names in one variable, for instance:

```
const names = "Alex Kyle Aaron";
```

You can do:

```
const arrayOfNames = names.split(" "); 
console.log(arrayOfNames); // ["Alex", "Kyle", "Aaron"]
```

Hope that helped! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
let stringValue='Jane Doe John Smith Rose Benet';
let stringList = stringValue.split(' ');
let resultList=[];

stringList.forEach((item,index)=> { if(index%2){ resultList.push(stringList[index-1]+' '+item);  } });

console.log(resultList);
```

resultList => ["Jane Doe", "John Smith", "Rose Benet"]

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```js
const arr = ["Jane Doe", "John Smith", "Rose Banet"]
```

Javascript can simply create an array with `[]` and of course you can put data into there delimiting with several commas.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
var data = `
Test Name
Pizza Cheese
Hello World
`;

console.log(data.split('\n').filter(n => n != ''));
```

Comment: I am assuming your data may have line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of `customerData` you can get an array containing the "name" property of every object in `customerData` simply with:

```
customerData.map(customer => customer.name);
```

In action:

```js
let customerData = [
  {
   "index": 0,
   "name" : "A",
   "gender" : "male",
   "company" : "CC"
  },
  {
   "index": 0,
   "name" : "B",
   "gender" : "female",
   "company" : "DD"
}];
console.log(customerData.map(customer => customer.name));
```